# How to check that a string WAS reversed using strrev() in PHP

Tags: php, string, passwords

Now I understand how to reverse a string in PHP:

```
<?php
echo strrev("Hello world!"); // outputs "!dlrow olleH"
?>
```

However, I have searched high and low and cannot figure out how to do what I want to do. (This is for a class project fyi)

I need to check that the password is the exact reverse of the username. So the user may choose whatever they want, but their password must be the exact reverse in order for them to proceed and log into the page.

EX:
username: me
Password: em

I do not need to store this in a file, just hard code it into the PHP script and have it check to make sure the one text field is the reverse of the other.

In theory (and I'm really new to this), I was thinking I should do something like this:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
echo ($_POST['password'] === strrev($_POST['username'])) ? 'true' : 'false'; // check    that password is reverse of username
?>
```

However, this is obviously not right (or I wouldn't be here). No matter what I put it, it is allowing the user to go on to the next page.

Full code:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
echo ($_POST['password'] === strrev($_POST['username'])) ? 'true' : 'false'; // check that password is reverse of username
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="amanot.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><label>Username: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Password: </label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Submit</label></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the values of `$username` and `$password`? If they are both empty strings, then it will echo true. Please show the form markup.

Comment: If you have a string $x and reverse it, then reverse it a second time you should have a string that exactly matches $x again

Comment: see above, I edited the question to include full code

Comment: But simply reversing a username and using that as the password is barely more secure than not bothering with a password at all

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, I completely agree, it's for a class project.

Comment: Try `if($password == strrev($username))`

Comment: @Fred-ii- it still let it through to the next page even if that wasn't true... hmmm... wish phpfiddle.org was working! :(

Comment: I tested what I put as my answer below @shannonmac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

I noticed you used my (*original*) answer in its entirety, but named it as an `.html` extension. That will not work.

Use two seperate files. One as `.html` for the form and the other as `amanot.php` for the action file.

My original answer had `action=""` instead of what you were using, plus there was a `\` at the end of `.../amanot.php\` in your file --- Try this now:

HTML form (form.html)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="amanot.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><label>Username: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Password: </label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Submit</label></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP (amanot.php) as a seperate file, not inside the form itself, it will not work.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($password == strrev($username)){
echo "match"; // replace with header("Location: valid.php"); exit;
}

else{
echo "sorry"; // replace with header("Location: invalid.php"); exit;
}

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
```

---

### Original answer

This works:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($password == strrev($username)){
echo "match"; // replace with header("Location: valid.php"); exit;
}

else{
echo "sorry"; // replace with header("Location: invalid.php"); exit;
}

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><label>Username: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Password: </label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Submit</label></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if this helps, here is the URL, I used your code, but incorrect username and password reverse combos are still going through
http://bctdigital.com/~student4/amanot.html

Comment: I got this error message back `The requested URL /~student4/php/amanot.php\ was not found on this server.` so there's something not properly coded @shannonmac My code works as one file, with form and PHP in one. Just replace the filenames for the header and delete the `echo`'s

Comment: ok i'm trying to go to another page if the username and password are accepted. Weird, I'm not getting the same error here, ugh it's a Friday night, my brain is DONE! I'm 100% sure this is something on my end!

Comment: I know the feeling, believe me. @shannonmac When `brain=mush`, it's time to take a break lol

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, if using just as is (as shown above) it would need to have the `.php` extension, just saying @shannonmac Yours has the `.html` extension.

Comment: Your file didn't work because it has the `.html` extension. Name your file `amanot.php` instead of `amanot.html` @shannonmac I could see the PHP code in the source, which is not supposed to show up like that. Plus change `action="http://bctdigital.com/~student4/php/amanot.php\"` to just `action=""` I will post an alternate answer with explanations.

Comment: @shannonmac I posted an edited version with explanations as to why it did not work in my answer.

Comment: ok it works minus the "if(isset($_POST['submit'])){" part
so I ended up doing:
<?php 
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password']; 
if($password == strrev($username)){ 
echo "<p style='color:green'>You have successfully logged in!</p>"; //what to do if condition is met 
}else{ 
echo "<p style='color:red'>Please enter the correct information.</p>"; // what to do if condition is not met 
} 
?>

Comment: gave a plus one b/c seriously thanks for all the hard work helping!

Comment: I was glad to have helped @shannonmac Cheers and thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, You are right mate . :) Perfect answer !

Answer (score 0):

That logic should be correct. If by 'next page' you mean the page that your PHP script is executing on, then that is the correct behavior.

If you would like to stop the current page from loading, try this instead.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if($_POST['password'] !== strrev($_POST['username'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
else {
    echo 'Successful';
}
?>
```

Comment: it is still letting it through even if it isn't the reverse

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think of that would be causing a mismatch would be text padding in the text inputs. Try trimming your characters using the trim function.